# 1195: Attempted access of inaccessible method ?

Tags: flash, actionscript

hi i have this really basic class here .. and i want to use setter and getter functions but i cant access them here is my code

the class which is in a folder called classes and file name is ColorPicker.as

```
package classes {
    import flash.display.*;
    public class ColorPicker extends Sprite {
        private var _width:uint = 50;
        //private var _height:uint;
        private var BG:Shape = new Shape();

        public function ColorPicker ():void
        {
            BG.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
            BG.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 90, 90);
            BG.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(BG);

        }
        public function get Wd () :uint 
        {
            return _width; 

        }       
        public function set Wd ( h:Number) :void 
        {
            _width = h ; 

        }
    }

}
```

my code in time line

```
import classes.ColorPicker ; 
var cp:ColorPicker = new ColorPicker () ; 
trace(cp.Wd());
```

if i tried to access the function with out the get or the set i would have no problems .. could someone explain whats happening to me .. thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public function get Wd():uint` declares a new property, not a function.

You access properties similar to how you'd access an attribute:

```
trace( cp.wd ); //will trace out the value
cp.wd = 5;
trace( cp.wd ); //should trace out 5
```

<sub>*"CP" has an internet cultural meaning that is likely unintended, please try to use more descriptive variable names to avoid embarrassing situations.</sub>

Comment: thanks for you help ... im not using those names for my class cuz as you said they are confusing and bad practices .